# Am I even burdened with choosing where and how to decode my video?

Tags: video, codec

Whenever I setup K-Lite codec pack, like during an MPC install, this step of K-Lite always trips me up:

[image]

It is never clear to me what is going on. No matter what I choose I will first have to decide what software package I am going to use to handle decoding and splitting.

[image]

The defaults seem to work but it is not made clear why this is important enough for me to care about.

Then comes hardware acceleration:

[image]

If I choose the "Simple" setup mode then I don't see this screen and I don't get to know if it is choosing software decoding because it is the first option in the list or because it is the best option for my system. Likewise if I choose a different setup mode I don't know if it is choosing software decoding because it is the first option or if it's the best option. Even further the options I am given to choose from have cryptic names. Am I given these options because my system supports them or because K-Lite does? I have no way of knowing.

As a layman I would just want video decoding to work optimally for my system. As someone with some technical knowledge I would want it to be decoded via hardware if I had it available and if I was an advanced user I would know exactly where I wanted it to be decoded.

Is it possible for software to detect what my system is capable of? Is the K-Lite installer already doing this?

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: Why do you even consider K-Lite. Use VLC, that can play anything. http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html

Comment: @whs k-lite has other uses besides video consumption. Other application workflows can depend on the codecs that it provides

Comment: Maybe K-lite is better now. But years ago when I tried to use it I had nothing but problems. And for playback it is certainly not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The additional settings impact video/audio quality and system resource utilization during playback. Some people want to control how their videos are decoded on their systems - this is mostly a matter of preference.

It is not likely to be practical for these selections to be simply based on one's hardware configuration. I cannot speak to whether or not the K-lite installer is detecting hardware.

Users who don't need this level of control can just click-thru and use the setup defaults.

Comment: "impact video/audio quality and system resource utilization during playback. " and "not likely to be practical for these selections to be simply based on one's hardware configuration" this is where I am confused